# Change column names or properties of an Excel worksheet via Linq

Tags: c#, excel, linq, linq-to-excel

I'm wondering how to raise the column names or properties of a worksheet into UPPERCASE without knowing how many there are or what their contents is?

My current code is as follows:

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(fileLocation);
var dataSheet = from c in excel.Worksheet(0) select c;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column names are on the first row of the worksheet, I recommend using the `WorksheetNoHeader()` method that LinqToExcel provides. You can then retrieve the first row and loop through all column names.

Here's a code example of what that could look like:

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(fileLocation);
var firstRow = excel.WorksheetNoHeader().First();

var columnNames = new List<string>();
foreach (var cell in firstRow)
  columnNames.Add(cell.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the open Office library.

Below code will give you the column text in upper case (considering 1st row has column names)

```
List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();
var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);
var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();

foreach (var r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
{
    var columnIndex = 0;
    if (r.RowIndex == "1") // Column Header
    {
        foreach (var c in r.Elements<Cell>())
        {
            columnNames.Add(GetCellValue(spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart, c).ToUpper());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to do this would be to isolate the appropriate cells (the ones that stand for the column names of your table) from the variable `dataSheet` (you could do this by looping, hardcoding or (ideally) by more efficient means, if you know of one). Then use the `String#toUpper()` method to raise each one of the String values into uppercase & inject them back into their respective cells.